# Add multiple pages within ArcGIS Pro layout?

Tags: arcgis-pro, pdf

I'm creating a 6 page Map-Series enabled PDF document. The first page has a map frame and dynamic text boxes all linked to a map series layer/attributes. The remaining 5 pages contain static text which will never change.

How can I add multiple pages to a layout? I can't see any options.

Comment: Simply put, a layout is a page.  Multiple pages = multiple layouts.  If you're creating a map-series, set one to the extent you want, and the other 5 to another extent with your static text using dynamic text to change from the first to 2-6

Answer (score 1):

I see no need for Map Series enablement unless you are trying to do the below for many 6-page PDFs using an Index Layer.

Since only one of your 6 pages needs to have a map I think you should export the layout with that map to make a PDF file.

Your 5 static text pages can then be created by exporting perhaps Word document(s) to PDF files.

You can then use the [PDFDocument class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm) in ArcPy to open the map PDF file and append the other PDF files as pages into it.  The PDFDocument class:

> Allows for the management of PDF documents, including facilities for
>   merging and deleting pages, setting document open behavior, and
>   creating or changing document security settings.

If you did want to do the above for many 6-page PDFs using an Index Layer, then you could use a Map Series to export single page PDF files for each map, and then use similar code to append the 5 static text pages to each.

Comment: I do need Map Series as I will be creating 100s of Page 1''s at a time, each with an updated map extent. 
I did end up exporting each page 1 to PDFs named by page number and then using python code to merge each exported page 1 PDF with the page 2-6 PDF.

I used arcpy.mp.PDFDocumentCreate and pdfDoc.appendpages to do this.